# Can AWS Glue use webservice as data source

Tags: aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

AWS offers S3, JDBC, and DynamoDB as datascore. Can I add REST endpoint as a data source? How can I build a glue workflow that gets data from a REST endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is a job to fetch REST Endpoint and save it into S3 or Database.

Refer to https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/use-aws-glue-to-run-etl-jobs-against-non-native-jdbc-data-sources/